# Is Jetty 9 NIO only?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, nio

I am going to use Jetty web server to handle websocket connections.
According to [the documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-config-what.html)

> From Jetty 9 onwards there is only one
>   prime Connector type (ServerConnector), which is NIO based and uses
>   Connection Factories to handle one or more protocols.

So, does it mean that Jetty has special Connection Factory for websockets and uses it with prime Connector type (ServerConnector), which is NIO based?

And I need nothing to "tune" in Jetty to process requests with NIO.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is purely based on what I've read in / understood from the documentation.

> Is Jetty 9 NIO only?

Apparently, yes.  Or at least for for server-side communication with clients.  (That part of the documentation is talking solely about the server-side connection classes.)

> So, does it mean that Jetty has special Connection Factory for websockets and uses it with prime Connector type (ServerConnector), which is NIO based?

I don't think it means that.  In fact, I suspect that a connection created by one of the other protocols (HTTP, HTTPS, AJP, SPDY) is used by the websocket implementation.  Websockets work by "upgrading" an the initial connection to a websocket.  There is already a connection created before a request gets to the WebsocketServlet implementation (or whatever).

So there should be no special connection factory for websockets.  And I couldn't find one when I took a quick look at the Jetty source code / javadocs.

> And I need nothing to "tune" in Jetty to process requests with NIO.

I think that is correct.  Under the hood, the websockets implementation will be using the one and only prime Connector type ... which is NIO based.